# jquery OnHoverOver and OnHoverOut

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net animation extendeer like this:

```
aspext:AnimationExtender ID="extender" TargetControlID="Panel1" runat="server">
            Animations>
                OnLoad>StyleAction Attribute="backgroundColor" Value="red" />/OnLoad>
                OnClick>StyleAction Attribute="backgroundColor" Value="blue" />/OnClick>
                OnMouseOver>StyleAction Attribute="backgroundColor" Value="pink" />/OnMouseOver>
                OnMouseOut>StyleAction Attribute="backgroundColor" Value="yellow" />/OnMouseOut>
                OnHoverOver>StyleAction Attribute="color" Value="orange" />/OnHoverOver>
                OnHoverOut>StyleAction Attribute="color" Value="purple" />/OnHoverOut>
            /Animations>
        /aspext:AnimationExtender>
```

I want to perform OnHoverOver and OnHoverOut using jquery. what are the events for these. I tried hover but it is not working. Basically I am calling jquery triggerevent and I need to pass event name. I am not sure what will be events names for these two. I tried others like click etc and they worked.

Comment: I am already using onmouseover and onmouseout for third and fourth. Aren't OnHoverOver and OnHoverOut different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#selector').hover(function(){
  //do something, this is for hoverover
  },function(){
  //do something this is for hoverout 
})
```

next method :

```
$("#selector").mouseover(function(){
  //do something, for hoverover
}).mouseout(function(){
   //do something, for hoverout
});
```

another method :

```
$("#selector").mouseenter(function(){
  //do something, for hoverover
}).mouseleave(function(){
   //do something, for hoverout
});
```

Comment: @Parkash: How to change my statement   QUnit.triggerEvent($testFrame('#Panel1')[0], "hover"); I need to put eventname in place of hover and $testFrame = $ in this case.

Comment: How to replace hover with mouseenter ?

Comment: @sparrow, I don't know asp.net so, i couldn't figure-out what you mean, just explain me what u want to do, i could help u on jquery.